# What shell use if I run a script with sudo before

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sudo, root

I have this script with name example.sh.

```
echo Write a number, please:
read x
let res=$x+1
echo $res
```

If i run it this way, I get an error:

```
mario@gazpatxo-linux:~/temp$ sudo ./example.sh 
[sudo] contraseña para mario: 
Write a number, please:
3
./example.sh: 3: ./example.sh: let: not found
```

If i run it this other way, I don't get an error:

```
mario@gazpatxo-linux:~/temp$ sudo su
root@gazpatxo-linux:/home/mario/temp# ./example.sh 
Write a number, please:
4
5
```

In the second default run I use / bin / bash, which is root's default shell, so it works correctly, but what happens in the first run? What shell am i using? Where can i change it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should add a "shebang" to your script. See for example [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no hashbang… but run as sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480830/which-shell-interpreter-runs-a-script-with-no-hashbang-but-run-as-sudo)

Comment: I get the same as you, which is interesting because all situations show the same default shell in `env`, being `SHELL=/bin/bash`. I upvoted your question and also up'd @steeldriver 's comment.

Comment: O.K. yes, sudo seems to force sh (if there is not shebang line) which has been pointing to dash instead of bash for several years now.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this as well and if the example.sh is not marked as executable it gave me the same error.

This command should make the file executable.

`sudo chmod +x example.sh`

Also you should add the shebang `#!/bin/bash` as steeldriver mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer to my question.

With the command "dpkg-reconfigure dash" a window opens that indicates that the default dash is associated with "/bin/sh" and allows us to change it to "/bin/bash", so now I can run the second situation without error, since due to the dash configuration, it would be executed with /bin/bash that recognizes the let command.